# How to copy/paste code from one file to another without loosing VCS history

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio/Intellij, is there a way to copy a chunk of code from one file to another without loosing the history.

For example: Highlighting a word --> right click --> Refactor --> Copy: permits to copy a class to another location while keeping the history of the whole class.

Is there a way to do the same thing just for a piece of code using the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't control the VCS history. The history is only managed by the git and it doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Can you please share the appropriate doc for that?